# Pandas best way to iterate over rows quickly

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare each value of a list to each value of a df column, and if there is a match take the value of another column.

I have a couple of loops working with iterrows but the code is taking a long time to run. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this? It seems .loc might be a good answer but the docs aren't super clear on how to make it work for this usecase.

My code so far is

```
listy = []
for view in joined_views:
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if view == row[1]['other_view']:
            listy.append(row[1]['other_column']
```

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Make your list a `pd.Series`. Merge it on your column while having the other column attached.

Comment: Notice from my answer that reproducible pandas examples don't need to be difficult.

Comment: It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: The best way is to avoid loops. Eventually you can use `map` or `apply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is built to apply operations across a group of data. `iterrows` is a relatively slow process to use when a group operation isn't available. In your case, `isin` will select the rows you want, and then you can grab the other column.

This can be written as

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"other_view":[1,2,3,4,5], 
    "other_column":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]})
joined_views = [1, 4, 100, 900, 1000]
listy = df[df.other_view.isin(joined_viewss)].other_column
print(listy)
```

or, if you prefer to name the columns as strings

```
df[df["other_view"].isin(joined_views)]["other_column"]
```

In words, select df rows where other_view is in joined_views, then take the other_column values.

Comment: it perhaps depends on what they'll do with `listy` afterwards but using `loc` as `df.loc[...isin(...), "other_column"]` [might be better](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) i guess. @hselbie